# GLFW Scroll wheel delta in a game loop

Tags: java, c++, game-engine, glfw

Im trying to retrieve a scroll wheel delta for camera zooming.

I've got a glfw scroll event callback that gives me an int of -1 or 1 depending on the scroll direction when the event occurs.

```
glfwSetScrollCallback(window, mouseScrollCallback = new GLFWScrollCallback() {

    @Override
    public void invoke(long window, double xOffset, double yOffset) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Everything else is as usual, there is a game loop and access to the frametime / delta time.

I want the delta to be "well behaved", how you'd intuitively understand it. 0 by default, and briefly -n or n depending on the amount of scrolling.

I've experimented by accumulating the offset, and then decreasing it again in the game loop but it doesn't seem to fit no matter how i do it.

Comment: how is this both java and c++?

Comment: My implementation is in Java, GLFW is a C++ API. I thought both sides would be able to say something about this.